# convert ruby hash to URL query string ... without those square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, uri, parameters

In Python, I can do this:

```
>>> import urlparse, urllib
>>> q = urlparse.parse_qsl("a=b&a=c&d=e")
>>> urllib.urlencode(q)
'a=b&a=c&d=e'
```

In Ruby[+Rails] I can't figure out how to do the same thing without "rolling my own," which seems odd. The Rails way doesn't work for me -- it adds square brackets to the names of the query parameters, which the server on the other end may or may not support:

```
>> q = CGI.parse("a=b&a=c&d=e")
=> {"a"=>["b", "c"], "d"=>["e"]}
>> q.to_params
=> "a[]=b&a[]=c&d[]=e"
```

My use case is simply that I wish to muck with the values of some of the values in the `query-string` portion of the URL. It seemed natural to lean on the standard library and/or Rails, and write something like this:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/foo?a=b&a=c&d=e")
q = CGI.parse(uri.query)
q.delete("d")
q["a"] << "d"
uri.query = q.to_params # should be to_param or to_query instead?
puts Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

but only if the resulting URI is in fact `http://example.com/foo?a=b&a=c&a=d`, and not `http://example.com/foo?a[]=b&a[]=c&a[]=d`. Is there a correct or better way to do this?

Comment: I did see http://bit.ly/gc2Ylj, which prompted me to quickly write https://gist.github.com/774142, which I *think* accomplishes what I want. Though what I wanted was *not* to roll my own. :-)

Answer (score 39):

In modern ruby this is simply:

```
require 'uri'
URI.encode_www_form(hash)
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for stdlib-2.1.0:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form

Answer (score 7):

**Quick Hash to a URL Query *Trick* :**

```
"http://www.example.com?" + { language: "ruby", status: "awesome" }.to_query

# => "http://www.example.com?language=ruby&status=awesome"
```

*Want to do it in reverse?* Use CGI.parse:

```
require 'cgi' 
# Only needed for IRB, Rails already has this loaded

CGI::parse "language=ruby&status=awesome"

# => {"language"=>["ruby"], "status"=>["awesome"]}
```

Comment: to_query is standard method or ruby Hash?

Comment: @gorn no, it is rails specific, see [`Hash#to_query`](https://devdocs.io/rails~6.0/hash#method-i-to_query)

Comment: I'm doing 11 years RoR never heard of `{}.to_query` Wow ! that's briliant !

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick function to turn your hash into query parameters:

```
require 'uri'
def hash_to_query(hash)
  return URI.encode(hash.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&"))
end
```

Comment: This sorts the keys in alphabetical order

Comment: This does not properly escape keys or values.

Comment: Don't use this. It will fail if any key or value contains `=` or `&`

Answer (score 0):

The way rails handles query strings of that type means you have to roll your own solution, as you have.  It is somewhat unfortunate if you're dealing with non-rails apps, but makes sense if you're passing information to and from rails apps.

Answer (score -2):

As a simple plain Ruby solution (or RubyMotion, in my case), just use this:

```
class Hash
  def to_param
    self.to_a.map { |x| "#{x[0]}=#{x[1]}" }.join("&")
  end
end

{ fruit: "Apple", vegetable: "Carrot" }.to_param # => "fruit=Apple&vegetable=Carrot"
```

It only handles simple hashes, though.