# Trouble passing params into GET request - Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that issues a GET request to a restful API, but it ignores the params that I'm trying to pass in. I want to just get the activated users but it returns *all* of the users.

Am I not passing in my params correctly? This is my script:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'time'
require 'api-auth'
require 'json'

URL = 'https://<instance name>.mingle-api.thoughtworks.com/api/v2/users.xml'
OPTIONS = {:access_key_id => '<sign in name>', :access_secret_key => '<secret key>'}
PARAMS = {:user => { :activated => true } }

def http_get(url, options={}, params)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  body = params.to_json

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.body = body
  request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  request['Content-Length'] = body.bytesize

  ApiAuth.sign!(request, options[:access_key_id], options[:access_secret_key])

  response = http.request(request)
  users = response.body

  if response.code.to_i > 300
    raise StandardError, <<-ERROR
    Request URL: #{url}
    Response: #{response.code}
    Response Message: #{response.message}
    Response Headers: #{response.to_hash.inspect}
    Response Body: #{response.body}
    ERROR
  end
  puts users
end

http_get(URL, OPTIONS, PARAMS)
```

The response is XML of users, formatted like this:

```
<user>
<id type="integer">2228</id>
<name>NAME</name>
<login>example@example.com</login>
<email>example@example.com</email>
<light type="boolean">false</light>
<icon_path nil="true"></icon_path>

<activated type="boolean">true</activated>
<admin type="boolean">false</admin>
</user>
```

I'm still a beginner when it comes to coding, so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the request that is actually going out to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the parameters for the get request in the body, when you should be placing them in the URL, so that the end of the URL looks something like this:

```
?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Use a function like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312888/3739861)):

```
require 'uri'
def hash_to_query(hash)
  return URI.encode(hash.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&"))
end
```

When you create the URI:

```
uri = URI.parse("#{url}?#{hash_to_query(params)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the params via the URL did not work for me.

I ended up pulling the data from the XML that was returned instead of narrowing the search. This returns the correct data:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'time'
require 'api-auth'
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'

URL = 'https://<instance name>.mingle-api.thoughtworks.com/api/v2/users.xml'
OPTIONS = {:access_key_id => '<sign in name>', :access_secret_key => '<secret key>'}

def http_get(url, options={})
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  ApiAuth.sign!(request, options[:access_key_id], options[:access_secret_key])

  response = http.request(request)
  users = response.body

  if response.code.to_i > 300
    raise StandardError, <<-ERROR
    Request URL: #{url}
    Response: #{response.code}
    Response Message: #{response.message}
    Response Headers: #{response.to_hash.inspect}
    Response Body: #{response.body}
    ERROR
  end
  return users
end

def extract_active_users
  all_users = Nokogiri::XML(http_get(URL, OPTIONS))
  all_users.search('//user').each do |user|
    active_user = user.xpath('activated')
    if active_user.text == 'true'
      puts user
    end
  end
end

extract_active_users
```